# Extracting the Model Object in R from str()

Tags: r

I have a logit model object fit using `glm2`.  The predictors are continuous and time varying so I am using basis splines. When I `predict(FHlogit, foo..,)` the model object it provides a prediction. All is well.

Now, what I would like to do is extract the part of `FHLogit` and the basis matrix the provides the prediction.  I do not want to extract information about the model from `str(FHLogit)` I am trying to extract the part that says `Beta * Predictor = 2`.  So, I can manipulate the basis matrix for each predictor

Comment: If you can't find the value you want in `str(FHLogit)`, look at the code for `print.glm2` or `summary.glm2` (or whatever `class(FHlogit)` returns...not sure if it's glm2).  It's in there somewhere.

Comment: Did you look at `ls(FHlogit)`?

Comment: I will take a look in the areas that you have recommended.  Heading out for the weekend to review my book with a referee tomorrow. Its glm2 so I know its gotta be there.  Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using basis splines will affect this. If so, please provide a reproducible example.

Here's a simple case:

```
df1 <- data.frame(y=c(0,1,0,1),
                  x1=seq(4),
                  x2=c(1,3,2,6))
library(glm2)
g1 <- glm2(y ~ x1 + x2, data=df1)
### default for type is "link"
> stats::predict.glm(g1, type="link")
          1           2           3           4 
 0.23809524  0.66666667 -0.04761905  1.14285714
```

Now, being unsure how these no.s were arrived at we can look at the source for the above, with `predict.glm`. We can see that type="link" is the simplest case, returning

```
pred <- object$fitted.values # object is g1 in this case
```

These values are the predictions resulting from *the original data* * *the coefficients*, which we can verify with e.g.

```
all.equal(unname(predict.glm(g1, type="link")[1]),
          unname(coef(g1)[1] + coef(g1)[2]*df1[1, 2] + coef(g1)[3]*df1[1, 3]))
```